# Why can't I use the gtest ValuesIn generator with a std::map?

Tags: c++, templates, googletest

I'm trying to run some tests on the elements of a map with gtest in the following way:

```
typedef std::map< std::string, std::vector< std::string > > maptype;

static maptype generateMapOfElements() {...}

class MyTest : public TestWithParam< maptype::value_type > {
...
}

TEST_P(MyTest , my_first_test) { .. }

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(test_prefix,
                        MyTest,
                        ValuesIn( generateMapOfElements() ) ); // <- problem
```

the problem seems that instantiating `pair::swap` is creating problems since the map's key is a **const** string (full log below)

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(48): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstring(912): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&) throw()'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstring(969): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstring(987): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstring(992): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const std::string, const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(56) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::swap<_Ty>(_Ty &,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(107) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Swap_adl<_Ty1>(_Ty &,_Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=std::string,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(104) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::swap(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const std::string,
1>              _Ty2=std::vector<testing::internal::string>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(211) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::swap(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const std::string,
1>              _Ty2=std::vector<testing::internal::string>
1>          ]
1>          C:\dir\my_test.cpp(251) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const std::string,
1>              _Ty2=std::vector<testing::internal::string>
1>          ]
```

Comment: How about using `class MyTest : public TestWithParam< std::pair<maptype::key_type, maptype::mapped_type> > {` ?

Comment: The type's different in that case, here's the error: http://nopaste.info/18a38842e5.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ValuesIn` function returns a generator that retains a copy of the values, and that copy is stored in a `vector`. (Why does it store a copy? Because in general, it can't rely on the original value source to remain valid for the lifetime of the test.) One of the requirements for `vector` is that its element type must be assignable (C++03, §23.1/3). However, as you've already noticed, `map::value_type` is `pair<const Key, T>`. The const key type prevents the type from being assignable.

Instead of a `map<string, vector<string>>` from your generator function, you might consider returning a `vector<pair<string, vector<string>>>`.

Comment: I had found out that the problem was related to copies but I hoped there would be a better solution. I don't see any other right now so for me this is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, thanks. This should be documented, because right now the doc says:


_ValuesIn(container) or ValuesIn(begin,end): Yields values from a C-style array, an STL-style container, or an iterator range [begin, end)._

It says nothing about not using std::map